# How can I calculate the Unix time taking into account the time zone?

Tags: oracle, timezone, unix-timestamp

Example:

```sql
SELECT
    SESSIONTIMEZONE,
    DT,
    TRUNC( (DT - date '1970-01-01') * 86400) AS EPOCH_DT
FROM "test_table"
```

outputs

| SESSIONTIMEZONE | DT | EPOCH_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Europe/Paris | 1970-01-02 00:00:00 | 86400 |

The desired output (tz_offset +01:00) would look like this:

| SESSIONTIMEZONE | DT | EPOCH_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Europe/Paris | 1970-01-02 00:00:00 | 82800 |

How could the following be changed so that the time zone is taken into account when calculating the Unix time?

```sql
TRUNC( (DT - date '1970-01-01') * 86400)
```

Comment: What data type is `DT`? And why would the value stored in your table depend on your *session* time zone - surely that should represent a definite point in time, either as a UTC-adjusted date/timestamp, or stored as a timestamp with time zone? Otherwise someone else running the same query can get a different 'epoch' result, which doesn't sound correct.

Comment: @AlexPoole, @MT0: I would like to rebuild MySQL's `unix_timestamp` for some database types: [github file](https://github.com/kuerbis/App-DBBrowser/blob/master/lib/App/DBBrowser/Table/Extensions/ScalarFunctions/SQL.pm) row 65 - 92.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert your date to a timestamp at a specific timezone (you appear to be wanting to use `SESSIONTIMEZONE`) and then you can convert that to a timestamp in the UTC time zone (using `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`) and back to a date so you can find the difference from the epoch time:

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE,
       DT,
       (
         CAST(
           FROM_TZ(
             CAST(DT AS TIMESTAMP),
             SESSIONTIMEZONE
           ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
           AS DATE
         )
         - DATE '1970-01-01'
       ) * 86400 AS EPOCH_DT
FROM   test_table
```

Which, for given the setup:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris';

CREATE TABLE test_table (dt) AS
SELECT DATE '1970-01-02' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SESSIONTIMEZONE | DT | EPOCH_DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Europe/Paris | 1970-01-02 00:00:00 | 82800 |

---

However, it may make more sense to store your value as a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` so that the time zone is stored with the data rather than trying to assume it from the time zone of the local session (otherwise you will get different epoch values for the same query and same data depending on where in the world the database thinks people are from).

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table2 (ts TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);
INSERT INTO test_table2 (ts) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-02 00:00:00 Europe/Paris');
```

Then you can use:

```
SELECT ts,
       (CAST(ts AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE) - DATE '1970-01-01')
       * 86400 AS EPOCH_DT
FROM   test_table2
```

Which outputs:

| TS | EPOCH_DT |
| --- | --- |
| 1970-01-02 00:00:00.000000000 EUROPE/PARIS | 82800 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xed5mGpZ)

---

If you want something that "works" for both `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then:

```sql
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE,
       DT,
       ROUND((CAST(CAST(dt AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATE) - DATE '1970-01-01') * 86400, 6) AS EPOCH_DT
FROM   test_table
```

However, I still do not think it is a good idea to assume the time zone for `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types based on the `SESSIONTIMEZONE`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oJEtEqEx)